# add selected radio value to search keyword on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

In my page I have two radios, user may select any one and type their search word in the input box, on button click I would like to append to their search keyword the value of selected radio?How do we do that in jquery or javascript?

So if they typed in Dance and selcted 'classes' the actual search keyword being passed will be 'Dance classes'

```
<div>
        Events<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Events"/>&nbsp;
        Classes<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Classes"/><br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="T1" style="width: 302px"/>
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
    var $this     = $(this),
        concocted = $this.prev().val() + ' ' + $this.prevAll('[type="radio"]:checked').val();

    //you can now do what you want with the `concocted` variable, which is in the format "{text-input} {radio input}"
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LAuZW/

Note that this code will work if you have more than one set of inputs since all the selectors are based off `this` which is the clicked button input.

Also note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this use-case is the same as `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Need some more information: are you wanting the additional keyword to be displayed in the text box as well?

All you really need to do is capture the value attr of the radio if checked in your SFSUBMIT function. jQuery has several different constructs to do this.

Comment: I just want to capture and pass it along with user typed in keyword value..not display

Comment: Then simple, if the values of the radio buttons will always be static, assign them an attribute with the value they will represent. Then in your function, simply use selectors to capture it and assign it to a var. Once it's in memory you can pretty much do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, when the user clicks the button, append what's in the textbox with the radio button currently checked?

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var text = $("input[name='EventRadio']:checked").val();
    if (text) {
        var $tb = $("input[name='T1']"); 
        $tb.val($tb.val() + text);
    }
});
```

Of course this will fire for **all** buttons - naturally you can add an id to this particular button an narrow the selector

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "button" ).live(
   'click',
   function (  )
   {
      $strVal = $( "[name='T1']" ).val(  ) . $( "[name='EventRadio']:checked" ).val(  );
      $( "[name='T1']" ).val( $strVal );
   }
);
```